# Casting a control to another page

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have tried everything to no avail. I need to cast the value from a user selected dropdownlist to another dropdownlist on another page. The data in the textboxes are a series of numbers.

Also is there a way to display the value in the second dropdown list as well as other values? For example, my dropdown has the values 1-6, user selects 4, which displays first in the dropdown on page 2 but the other values also display in case they want to change there selection??

```
If Not Page.PreviousPage Is Nothing Then
  Dim table As Control = PreviousPage.Controls(0).FindControl("table1")
  Dim ddl As DropDownList = CType(table.FindControl("ddlB_Codes"),c DropDownList)
If Not ddl Is Nothing Then
  ddl_OC.DataSource = ddl.SelectedValue.Substring(0, 6)
End If
End If
```

Quick update I FINALLY got my casting to work through a session, only now I need to know how to display the session values and the other additional values for my drop box in case the user wants to change something? Thanks for the help

```
ddl_OC.DataSource = CType(Session.Item("valCodes"), String)
ddl_OC.DataBind()
ddl_SO.DataSource = CType(Session.Item("valAccts"), String)
ddl_SO.DataBind()
```

Comment: You don't want to `cast`but `pass` the value from oner page to another. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6c3yckfw.aspx

Comment: Tried this already, I keep coming up with a null reference... Here is my code. The null reference is in the dim ddl for the dropdown. On my sourcepage I have a <table><tr><td>Control is in here</td></tr></table>

Answer (score 0):

Use event selectedvaluechanged to set datasource for another DropDownList, when first one is changed.
Don't forget to populate it vin DataBind function usage.